# C - getchar() producing erroneous output

Tags: c, getchar

I'm writing a program for my computing class that scores a tennis match. The program takes inputs for teams as 'A' and 'B' for teams, and 'S' to print the score out. It works fine until it gets to the deuce function.

The problem I'm having is that multiple inputs at one time break the program. So once the deuce has started, input of: 'A, Enter, B, Enter, B, Enter', works fine, but 'A, B, B, Enter' breaks it. Unfortunately the auto-marker at uni just shoves long strings of characters at it. This also makes it hard to test because I can't see what is happening at each stage of input.

I've got a while loop trying to consume some of the extra characters I was getting, but it's still not quite right. I've had problems before where an input of 'A' will output 'AA', I think it's something similar.

I'm just learning so I'm sure I just misunderstand how to use the getchar() function. Also I know there are parts of my code that could be simpler, but it's due really soon and I haven't had, and probably won't have, time to optimise it properly.

Thanks for any help!!!

EDIT: Sorry, reading back on my question I can see I worded it quite badly. It doesn't ever 'break' and -Wall gives no errors or warnings, it just gives the wrong output. For example, the input 'ABB' should go like this:

A: The program thinks that A has the advantage.

B: The program thinks that B has equalised, so the deuce restarts.

B: B should now have the advantage.

(If I hit 'Enter' after every input, the above output is exactly what happens.)
But if 'ABB' is typed in all at once, and then 'Enter' is pressed it exits the deuce function entirely, thinking that 'B' has won the deuce and keeps going with the normal tennis match. So I think what is happening is that an extra 'B' is being passed through the while loop.

```
void deuce ( int data_array[], int set_tally[], int team_select ){

int A_deuce_points = 0;
int B_deuce_points = 0;
int server = data_array[data_array[8]];
int ch = 0;
int winner = 0;

while ( A_deuce_points < 2 && B_deuce_points < 2){ // needs to be &&

    ch = getchar();
    printf("ch = %d\n", ch);
    while ( ch == 10 || ch == -1 || ch == '\n' ){
        ch = getchar();

    }

    if ( ch == 'A' ){

        A_deuce_points++;
    }
    else if (ch == 'B'){

        B_deuce_points++;
    }
    else if (ch == 'S' ){

        printf("Team %c to serve:\n", server);

        if ( server == 'A' ){

            // Print sets
            winner = server;
            print_completed_sets( set_tally, winner );

            // Print games
            printf("%d-%d\n", data_array[4], data_array[5]);

            if(A_deuce_points == B_deuce_points ){
                printf("Deuce\n");
                A_deuce_points = 0;
                B_deuce_points = 0;
            }
            if(A_deuce_points - B_deuce_points == 1 ){
                printf("Advantage Server\n");
            }
            if(B_deuce_points - A_deuce_points == 1 ){
            printf("Advantage Receiver\n");
            }
        }
        else if ( server == 'B' ){

            // Print sets
            winner = server;
            print_completed_sets( set_tally, winner );

            // Print games
            printf("%d-%d\n", data_array[5], data_array[4]);

            if(A_deuce_points == B_deuce_points ){
                printf("Deuce\n");
                A_deuce_points = 0;
                B_deuce_points = 0;
            }
            if(B_deuce_points - A_deuce_points == 1 ){
                printf("Advantage Server\n");
            }
            if(A_deuce_points - B_deuce_points == 1 ){
            printf("Advantage Receiver\n");
            }
        }
    }

}// end while loop

if ( A_deuce_points == 2 ){

    data_array[4]++;


}
else if ( B_deuce_points == 2 ){

    data_array[5]++;

}

data_array[2] = 0;
data_array[3] = 0;
A_deuce_points = 0;
B_deuce_points = 0;
change_serve( data_array);
}
```

Comment: Compile your program with all warning & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). **Use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: You do know that `10` and `'\n'` is the same in the ASCII character set?

Comment: Also, if `getchar` returns `EOF` (not `-1`) then you should stop reading.

Comment: `ABB` causes `B_deuce_points` to reach the value `2` which exists the `while` loop. After the while loop, you manipulate `data_array`. I guess that `data_array` is not initialised properly, so that might cause the crash.

Comment: Outside of `deuce()`, code has a some input function like `getchar();` that needs to eliminated.  Show calling code.

Comment: Thanks chux!!! That was it! I had two getchar() while loops one for main() and one for the deuce(). I have now changed my code around so that I used the getchar() in main and filtered the input down into deuce() if necessary. 

I up-voted your comment, you completely solved my problem,

Thanks